# Fazer copia de uma planilha filtrada no excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, filtro

Eu estou com um problema, eu preciso extrair uma listagem de dados do excel que eu filtrei com mais de 200 mil linhas, eu tenho a opção de fazer o excel analisar cada linha e deletar ela mas eu queria fazer isso sem perder os dado já presentes então eu pesquisei e achei um meio de só copiar o que é visível(que deixou ativo no filtro) mas com isso quando vou salvar a macro aquilo que só pesava 10mb ta pesando 16mb e o excel fica engasgando, isso não é interessante pois eu preciso enviar por email, se eu copiar manualmente o filtro e colar ele resolve mas eu preciso de agilidade. Alguém saberia o que tem de errado nesse código?

```
Sub extrair()

''''''''' limpa a planilha que vai receber a lista ''''''
Sheets("Base").Select 
Cells.Select
Range("A1").Activate
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''' insere o filtro CE  na coluna de estados '''''

Sheets("INF").Select

If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CB$1048575").AutoFilter Field:=68, Criteria1:="CE"
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''    


''''''''''''''''' seleção do filtro o que deve ser copiado ''''''''''''''''''''''
fimr = 1048576
contR = 1
contC = 1

Do While Cells(fimr, 68).Value <> "CE"
fimr = fimr - 1
Loop

contR = 1048576 - fimr

valor = Cells(1, contC).Value

Do While valor <> ""
contC = contC + 1
valor = Cells(1, contC).Value
Loop

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(contR, contC)).Select


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''' copia só o que está visível e cola na planilha Base''''''''''''
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets("Base").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' retorna ao local do botão da macro ''''''''''
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Macro").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a opção Localizar e Selecionar -> Ir para Especial -> Somente células visíveis, copiar e colar.

A seguir figura
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da Macro ficou assim:

```
 Range("A4:B11").Select
 Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Range("G9").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 1):

Vê se dessa forma é mais rápido com a quantidade de dados que tem: (esse trecho deve substituir a parte de seu código que copia, usá-lo após aplicar o filtro)

```
Call Plan1.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Call Plan2.Paste
```

Obs: Imaginei que está utilizando o filtro direto na planilha com dados (autofiltro).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Quando tenho que resolver esse tipo de situação eu uso o botão de opções do próprio excel para habilitar a opção Select Visibles, com as células filtradas eu copio e colo no destino usando o CTRL+C  e CTRL+V.

[File > Options > Quick Access Tool bar > troque popular commands para all commands e procure por Select Visible Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6SVP.png)

Após ter habilitado, basta filtrar sua base, selecionar as células visiveis e copiar e colar.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sou nova com `VBA`, e gostaria de pedir, por favor, a ajuda de vocês..

Tenho uma planilha `Excel` com uma determinada coluna, e preciso criar uma macro que faça o seguinte:

- Criar uma conexão com o Banco de dados, para ler uma coluna de uma determinada tabela, e verificar se cada registro da minha coluna do `Excel` consta na minha coluna do Banco, e se existir:
- Pegar registro a registro e filtrar no `Excel` um por um, e jogar cada um em um novo arquivo `Excel` diferente.
- Após isso, enviar por e-mail cada arquivo novo criado.

Ex: Planilha "Dados", possuo a coluna com o id da pessoa, terei que ver na minha tabela do banco se esse id existe, e se sim, filtrarei ele no meu `Excel`, criarei um novo arquivo `Excel` para salvar este registro, e enviarei este arquivo por e-mail a algumas pessoas. Terei que fazer isso para cada registro do meu `Excel` principal...

Vocês tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Bem vinda, você respondeu a uma pergunta ao invés de responder. Para saber mais veja aqui: pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -2):

Eu recomendo transformar a sua base maior em tabela e após aplicado o filtro copiar normalmente (Sem usar comando AutoFilter) fazendo referência com a tabela.

Ex.
Planilha1.Range("Venda_Globo[Ean]").Copy
Sheets("Base").Select
Range("A1").PasteSpecial.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).